# Cannot read queryParams in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to fetch queryParams from url with window.location but query params are not being grabbed.

Example my url is [www.abc.com?accountId=123#](http://www.abc.com?accountId=123#)
I am looking for a way to grab accountId=123 as a queryParam or atleast the entire url.

When I used window.location I am getting [www.abc.com/#/](http://www.abc.com/#/) instead of [www.abc.com?accountId=123#](http://www.abc.com?accountId=123#)

Why am I not able to read the query params?

Why am I not able to read the query params?

Answer (score 1):

according to the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) you can fetch the query parameters with the activatedRoute in Angular.

In the below example we grab a query parameter "name".

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params['name'];
  });
}
```